# MySQL subquery with between date

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, where-clause

My query is for calculating sales profit. To calculate cost price I need to take average cost for particular date. The below query works well if I have a single date, but for a **`range of dates`** `(replacing '=2014-12-30 ' with 'BETWEEN '2014-12-30' AND '2015-01-02' at both places)` it does not generate required output

```
SELECT sinvoiceno,sinvoicedate,pureweight,makingcharge,totalamount,rd.avgr ,
    (pureweight*rd.avgr)+makingcharge AS TotalCost ,
    totalamount-((pureweight*rd.avgr)+makingcharge) AS Profit 
FROM
    (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(gdate,'%Y-%m-%d') AS grDate,AVG(goldrate24) AS AvgR 
     FROM rate_detail r  
     GROUP BY grDate 
     HAVING grdate = '2014-12-30' ) AS rd,
    sales_master sm 
WHERE  sinvoicedate = '2014-12-30'
```

Comment: Please provide the output it gives and the output you expect to get. Thanks.

Comment: You're missing a joining condition between the subquery and the table. If you have multiple dates, it will produce a full cross-product.

Comment: Don't use old join syntax, use `ON` keyword. Also, don't use `between` (https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: Thank you every one i got my mistake,to date format need to be of same type.all i did is ,i make both date in same format and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need a joining condition so that you link rows of the subquery with `sales_master` on the same date.

```
SELECT sinvoiceno,sinvoicedate,pureweight,makingcharge,totalamount,rd.avgr ,
    (pureweight*rd.avgr)+makingcharge AS TotalCost ,
    totalamount-((pureweight*rd.avgr)+makingcharge) AS Profit 
FROM
    (SELECT DATE(gDate) AS grDate, AVG(goldrate24) AS AvgR 
     FROM rate_detail r 
     WHERE DATE(gDate) BETWEEN '2014-12-30' AND '2015-01-02' 
     GROUP BY grDate ) AS rd
JOIN sales_master sm ON sinvoicedate = grDate
WHERE sinvoicedate BETWEEN '2014-12-30' AND '2015-01-02'
```

Comment: Thank you every one i got my mistake,to date format need to be of same type.all i did is ,i make both date in same format and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT sinvoiceno, sinvoicedate, pureweight, makingcharge, 
       totalamount, rd.avgr, (pureweight * rd.avgr) + makingcharge AS TotalCost ,
       totalamount -((pureweight * rd.avgr) + makingcharge) AS Profit 
FROM (SELECT STR_TO_DATE(gdate,'%Y-%m-%d') AS grDate,AVG(goldrate24) AS AvgR 
      FROM rate_detail r  
      WHERE STR_TO_DATE(gdate,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2014-12-30' AND '2015-01-02'
      GROUP BY grDate
     ) AS rd,
INNER JOIN sales_master sm ON rd.grDate = sinvoicedate
WHERE sinvoicedate BETWEEN '2014-12-30' AND '2015-01-02';
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the `rd` subquery to return one row, an average over a period of time.  So, remove the `group by` and put in the appropriate bounds using `where`:

```
SELECT sm.sinvoiceno, sm.sinvoicedate, sm.pureweight, sm.makingcharge, sm.totalamount,
       rd.avgr, (sm.pureweight*rd.avgr) + sm.makingcharge AS TotalCost ,
       sm.totalamount-((sm.pureweight*rd.avgr)+sm.makingcharge) AS Profit 
FROM sales_master sm CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT AVG(goldrate24) AS AvgR 
      FROM rate_detail r  
      WHERE grDate = '2014-12-30'
     ) rd
WHERE sm.sinvoicedate = '2014-12-30';
```

You can then put a range in to expand the time period for the average.  For instance:

```
SELECT sm.sinvoiceno, sm.sinvoicedate, sm.pureweight, sm.makingcharge, sm.totalamount,
       rd.avgr, (sm.pureweight*rd.avgr) + sm.makingcharge AS TotalCost ,
       sm.totalamount-((sm.pureweight*rd.avgr)+sm.makingcharge) AS Profit 
FROM sales_master sm CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT AVG(goldrate24) AS AvgR 
      FROM rate_detail r  
      WHERE grDate BETWEEN '2014-12-30' AND '2015-01-02'
     ) rd
WHERE s.invoiceDate BETWEEN '2014-12-30' AND '2015-01-02';
```

EDIT:

It occurs to me that you want the average on a single date, which is the invoice date.  In that case:

```
SELECT sm.sinvoiceno, sm.sinvoicedate, sm.pureweight, sm.makingcharge, sm.totalamount,
       rd.avgr, (sm.pureweight*rd.avgr) + sm.makingcharge AS TotalCost,
       sm.totalamount-((sm.pureweight*rd.avgr)+sm.makingcharge) AS Profit 
FROM sales_master sm JOIN
     (SELECT date(grDate) as grDate, AVG(goldrate24) AS AvgR 
      FROM rate_detail r  
      WHERE BETWEEN '2014-12-30' AND '2015-01-02'
      GROUP BY date(grDate)
     ) rd
     ON rd.grDate = sm.s.invoicedate
WHERE s.invoiceDate BETWEEN '2014-12-30' AND '2015-01-02';
```

I am unclear as to whether or not the "date" columns have time components.  If so, then you want to use `date()` where appropriate.